# HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion - how do I set it to try 1.0, then 1.1 (or vice versa)?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

We have a commercial library and some of our customers need

```
HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10
```

and some need

```
HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version11
```

Is there a way to tell it to try both? Or do I need to add a configuration setting for the 1.0 people (yuck)?

[Also asked on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/188004/httpwebrequestprotocolversion-how-do-i-set-it-to-t.html)

Comment: Both of your code pieces are setting the same protocol version. Could you please fix the question?

Comment: I would assume that if you have provided a version which is not supported by the target server then it will throw a `WebException`. I would suggest that to give it a try and examine the thrown exception then use some heuristic to unambiguously spot that exception and retry the request with lower protocol version.

Comment: @PeterCsala I'm hoping to avoid that, I try to have it that code following the happy path does not throw exceptions. But you may be right as this is the only way to do it outside of a property.

Comment: As you can see the `Version` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version)) is defined as class not as enum. So, we can't use flags (like: `HttpVersion.Version10 | HttpVersion.Version11`). `HttpVersion.Version` ([2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpversion.version11)) is defined as static field.